# 4 Layers PCB stackup

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

I'm working with 4 layers PCB and setting layers stackup.
This is what Eagle shows me:
[image]

Do I need to add also layers for solder mask or anything else required for production ?

Comment: I've seen different CAD software handle it differently. Your PCB manufacturer won't complain if what you show in the picture is your inner structure and there are soldermask layers on top and bottom on top of that. Business as usual. Can you export your soldermask (and silk screen) as separate Gerber files?